# why require("angular") returns an empty object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webpack

I've configured webpack like this:

```
resolve: {
    alias: {
        angular: path.join(__dirname, './node_modules/angular/angular.js')
    }
},
```

and in my file I require angular like this:

```
var angular = require("angular");
```

But for some reason an empty object is returned, why?

Comment: Angular 1 doesn't support CommonJS modules, so it 'exports' an empty object.

Instead, just require it (without assigning the result):

require('angular')

Comment: yeah, it's working now, thanks, can you post it as an answer?

Comment: please check my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The other answers are not providing a working solution. It is true that Angular 1 is not working nicely with webpack out-of-the-box (see https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2049), but it can be loaded with a shim. Try this webpack loader config:

```
module: {
    loaders: [
        /*
         * Necessary to be able to use angular 1 with webpack as explained in https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2049
         */
        {
            test: require.resolve('angular'),
            loader: 'exports?window.angular'
        },
    ]
},
plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        'angular': 'angular',
    }),
],
```

This should initialize the angular object properly instead of the default action of setting it to an empty object (which does not have a property named module).

Answer (score 5):

The other answers aren't quite accurate - it's true that the core `angular.js` file doesn't support CommonJS, but if you install it from NPM, a tiny wrapper file called `index.js` is provided. It's literally just two lines:

```
require('./angular'); // Runs angular.js, which attaches to the window object
module.exports = angular; // Exports the global variable
```

This allows you to use it in CommonJS environments like normal. So if you update your config like so, it should work:

```
resolve: {
    alias: {
        angular: path.join(__dirname, './node_modules/angular/index.js')
    }
},
```

(That said, this should be Webpack's default behaviour even if you don't alias `angular`, as `index.js` is marked as Angular's main file in its `package.json` - you probably can get away with just using no alias at all!)

Comment: great, thanks for your suggestion, I'll definitely try it

Comment: This helps me a lot! Thanks!

Comment: For whatever reason, that wrapper does not do the trick. The "angular" variable after a require('angular') is an empty object, but window.angular contains the proper angular object. Thus this loader config is required: {test: require.resolve('angular'),loader: 'exports?window.angular'},

Comment: @Motin: Hm, that's strange, it definitely used to work for me without shimming the export. That said, it could have been a quirk of my project setup, or a change in Angular could have broken it. Thanks for providing an updated answer!

Answer (score 1):

Angular 1 doesn't support CommonJS modules, so it 'exports' an empty object.

> Instead, just require it (without assigning the result):

```
 require('angular')
```

Answer (score 1):

Conceptual answer -

**Angular 1.x** does not support `CommonJS` modules that's why following approach of exporting yields an `empty object`:

```
var angular = require("angular");
```

So better omit the `var angular` part and just make use of `require("angular");`